# Why is a correlation coefficient threshold of r = 0.6 among predictors commonly used in ecology?

Tags: correlation, multiple-regression, linear-model, multicollinearity, ecology

In my field of study (wildlife ecology), a correlation coefficient of  *r* = 0.6 is a commonly-used threshold for identifying collinearity among pairs of predictor variables. In other words, predictors with a correlation above *r* = 0.6 are generally not included in the same model.

I recently wrote in the draft of a manuscript: "*There was no strong collinearity detected among the predictor variables* (*all* *r* < 0.6)..." We only had 3 predictors. A colleague reviewed the draft and posited: "*r* < 0.6 *seems like a high threshold, can you briefly justify that*?"

**I don't have a good reference supporting the *r* < 0.6 threshold**, but there are several posts on this site where *r* < 0.6 is mentioned in passing when members have discussed possible collinearity in their data or lack thereof ([here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/14500/how-can-a-regression-be-significant-yet-all-predictors-be-non-significant/14528#14528), [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/137090/78339), and [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/159214/coefficient-with-df-0-in-log-binomial-model)). In other places (in a former stats class, as well as [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/100272/78339)), I've heard that VIF = 10 is an appropriate threshold, which corresponds approximately with *r* = 0.95 (i.e., for only two variables $VIF = 1/(1-0.95^2$).

All things considered, I think *r* = 0.6 may be a relatively conservative (low) threshold, rather than a high threshold as my colleague suggested. I plan on responding by saying that *r* = 0.6 is a conservative threshold for collinearity that gives us relatively good confidence that collinearity among predictors is not affecting our inference.

My question is:

1. Does anyone know where this "rule of thumb" of *r* < 0.6 could have emerged (a reference)?
2. If the cutoff is more or less arbitrary, do you think it is too low (conservative) or high (liberal)? Compared to when VIF = 10 (*r* = 0.95), it appears conservative.

Comment: how long is a piece of string? see e.g. Graham 2003 *Ecology*

Comment: Knowing that you have 3 predictors, which formula are you using to calculate the correlation coefficient?

Comment: I calculated Pearson's *r* for each pair of predictors.

Answer (score 7):

There is recent work showing that collinearity becomes a more serious problem (inflating the variance of estimated regression coefficients, and therefore not necessarily finding the 'significant' ones correctly) at r>0.7;

Dormann, C. F., J. Elith, S. Bacher, et al. 2013. Collinearity: a review of methods to deal with it and a simulation study evaluating their performance. Ecography 36:27–46.